# How do I Pattern Match on the actual container of Discriminated Union cases?

Tags: f#

Out of curiosity, how do I pattern match on the actual container of discriminated union cases?

Specifically, how can I know if a value is of a specific type?

I tried using the pattern construct (i.e. :?):

```
let isVehicle = fun a -> match a with
                         | :? Vehicle -> "Is a vehicle"
                         | _          -> "Is NOT a vehicle"
```

**Error:**

> This runtime coercion or type test from type
>       'a      to 
>       Vehicle     involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Runtime type tests are not allowed on
>   some types. Further type annotations are needed.

Here's the entire code:

```
type Vehicle = 
    | Car
    | Tank
    | Helicopter

let move = function
    | Car        -> "wheels spin"
    | Tank       -> "tracks roll"
    | Helicopter -> "Blades spin"

let isVehicle = fun a -> match a with
                         | :? Vehicle -> "Is a vehicle"
                         | _          -> "Is NOT a vehicle"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add type annotation to lambda parameter:

```
let isVehicle = fun (a:obj) -> match a with
                               | :? Vehicle -> "Is a vehicle"
                               | _          -> "Is NOT a vehicle"
```